# Which space is bigger? (Sobolev Space)

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, laplacian

First, let us define the following space :
\begin{align*}
H^{1}(\Omega) :=\{u :\Omega\to\mathbb{R}\,|\,\forall\alpha\text{ multiindex },0\leq|\alpha|\leq1,||D^{\alpha}u||_{L^{2}(\Omega)}<\infty\} \\
H^{2}(\Omega) :=\{u :\Omega\to\mathbb{R}\,|\,\forall\alpha\text{ multiindex },0\leq|\alpha|\leq2,||D^{\alpha}u||_{L^{2}(\Omega)}<\infty\}\\
\end{align*}
Then, we can define the corresponding space $H_{0}^{1}(\Omega) \subset H^{1}(\Omega)$ and $H_{0}^{2}(\Omega)\subset H^{2}(\Omega)$.

Finally we define the following :
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
D(B) := \{u \in H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)\,|\,\Delta u\in L^{2}(\Omega)\} \\
\forall u\in D(B), B u=\Delta u
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

I can immediately see by definition that $D(B)\subset H^{2}(\Omega)$. However, can anyone help me to construct a counter example or to show that $H_{0}^{2}(\Omega) \subset D(B)$?

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you very much!

Comment: If $u \in H_0^2(\Omega)$ then 1) $u \in H^2(\Omega)$ so that $\Delta u \in L^2(\Omega)$, and 2) $u \in H^1_0(\Omega)$. This gives you $u \in D(B)$.  How do you immediately see by definition that $D(B) \subset H^2(\Omega)$?

Comment: I think I made a mistake… Now I carefully reconsider the statement I realise that $D(B) \subset H^2(\Omega)$ does not hold